# Express render to load javascript before server-side code

Tags: express, socket.io

I need your help to solve an issue.
I use express and socket.io and I try to preload my client-side javascript (my client-side socket connection) before server-side code.

Currently, I do this :

Server-side :

```
app.get('/branche/:branche', function(req, res) {
    res.render('branchebuild', {branchname: branche, listCommande : listCommandeApplis}, function(err, html){
        if(html){ //callback dès que le template est chargé
            res.send(html);
            io.sockets.emit("resultStep", "foo");
        }
    });
});
```

Client-side (in a socket.js file) :

```
socket.on("resultStep", function(foo) { 
    console.log("coucou", foo);
});
```

The issue is server-side load faster than client-side so client-side can't use my socket.js function.

How can I solve this kind of problem ?
Thank's for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

Your `emit()` method is ran just after the HTML file is served to the client. Obviously, the client won't be quick enough to render the page, interpret the JS code and then start to listen to the web socket calls.

You need to either :

- Add in your JS code a client side `emit()` that the server will respond to with its own `emit()`. This will make sure the client fully rendered the page before interacting with the server.
- Pass `"foo"` through the `res.render()` method. This will immediately be sent to the client, without a single web socket call.